# App crashing on open on Motorola Backflip only

Tags: android, crash, motorola

I have recently published my second app on the Android Market. I've gotten a few e-mails about the app crashing on open, and all users were using the Motorola Backflip. It seems to work fine on all other devices. The app shows the background image, but crashes right after that.
Is there something different I have to do when coding for that device?

The strange thing is that it is very similar to my first app, which seems to work just fine for them. The major difference is that my second app is a paid app, and uses Android Licence Verification. My implementation should catch any license errors though, and I've tested this on my device.

Users have uninstalled and reinstalled the app without success. I'm stumped. 
The other thing they're reporting is that the icon doesn't even show properly, but rather is a gear in a box, which makes me think that something goes awry very early in the installation process.

Comment: The market doesn't show any error reports you can work on?

Comment: Welcome to the joy of OS fragmentation. I spent a whole day last week debugging a device-specific crash that turned out to be due to HTC's implementation of the Contacts content provider being subtly different from the stock one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to have a user install aLogcat on their phone to send me the log.

It had to do with onCreateDialog. I was returning several dialogs, but one of them actually called .show(), which it's not supposed to do, of course. The thing is that this didn't cause an error on any phones except for the Backflip. The emulators also didn't error, or even warn me about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a motorola backflip and i can say that is not a good product....it's crashing for a lot of things....don't worry, your app is not wrong, the phone is wrong...